# Programmatically Show iPhone VPN Connection Page

Tags: ios4, vpn

Is there a supported (or even known) way to display the VPN Connection Page programmatically? I haven't been able to find anything to the affirmative yet, but I'm hopeful. There's documentation on showing some of the [Standard Modal View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW4), but there aren't any related to any networking dialogs/pages. Any information would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded (after digging through the iOS SDK documentation) that this is not possible, unfortunately.